# Multiple SSH keys with Pageant, wrong user picked up when accessing GitHub

Tags: windows, ssh, git, github

I have two GitHub accounts (one professional and one personal).

GitHub forces us to use different SSH keys on different accounts, presumably because it uses SSH keys not only for authentication but also for identification (sigh... That means I can't use a single SSH key per machine, but that's another story).

I'm accessing GitHub repositories via SSH (not via HTTPS). I'm using Pageant on Windows, and both keys are loaded.

When I try to push to a repo under account A, everything's fine. When I try to push to a repo under account B however, I get the dreaded "permission denied" because it actually authenticates using the key from account A. I can tell because the error message says so:

```
ERROR: Permission to AccountB/repo.git denied to AccountA.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If that's relevant, I'm using Git Extensions (in standalone mode) as Git client.

This setup has been working just fine for more than a decade, unfortunately I recently renewed my keys and more generally refactored my SSH setup, and now it won't work properly anymore.

Any idea?

Edit 2020-03-30: For some reason it works again.

Comment: I don't think that you can use Pagent. Instead you have to manually configure the key in each repo settings as shown here: https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key/198614#198614

Comment: Thanks but as I said, this setup has been working for 10+ years without issue, using Pageant, until I decided to mess with my SSH keys. That said, you do have a point in that even Git Extensions has a way to associate an SSH key to a particular remote. It just doesn't change anything in this case.

Comment: AFAIR there was a message shown about an special GitHub API for git which was used by Git on Windows. May be this API was used before and was the one that used the correct key?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My git client hasn't changed so that can't be it, also I doubt there's a specific API for Git for Windows.